# Azure APIM API security with SPA angular application

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application, azure-api-management

I am having an angular application (hosted as a web app) that will consume APIs which are exposed through APIM. my concern is, If subscription key and CORS enough for security? or we have to implement any other security feature?

-Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Subscription Key is secure enough in general for service-to-service calls, for web apps it would difficult to use it as such. The better approach would be to use Azure AD (B2C) as required.

For this, you could still require CORS setup and in addition, setup OAuth2.0 based on authentication on your SPA and pass tokens in API requests which APIM can [validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c#set-up-the-cors-and-validate-jwt-policies).

The official doc [Protect SPA backend with OAuth 2.0, Azure Active Directory B2C and Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c) covers this in detail including all the steps required to set things up.

Comment: Thanks Promod, I was looking for something without Azure AD. How to secure the calls which are done publicly.  Since clientID and secrets will be visible on the angular application side. So generally in this case how can we secure the API calls

Comment: Even without Azure AD, you can still use any OAuth or OpenID Connect based authentication. Also, you should never really have the Client Secret as part of your client side web app.

Comment: Thanks Pramod, So the only issue is storing secret in client app. As my application has few public pages that can access the APIs, so here API calls will be made without user authentication. Not sure how to secure this. As my angular app directly calls the APIM api currently, so I cannot add server side code now for secrets. Shouldn't Azure front door with WAF and CORS enough for securing backend api? Any other suggestions?

Comment: CORS just prevents your API from being used on other domains and WAF while adds security in general, doesn't really protect your API. One could simply track requests being made from your web page and make those same requests outside the browser. If the APIs are meant to be anonymously accessed, then you are good and could even get rid of the secret totally.

Comment: Thanks, Pramod, for the quick responses. I would say APIs are not meant for anonymously accesses. These are the APIs that are on the registration pages, few get APIs and Post API to create the account. After login, we are all good. the issue is for these APIs, want to protect the subscription key which will be exposed through these APIs.